# Flutter FVM .vscode/settings.json is gone

Tags: flutter, dart

im using `fvm` to use `flutter 1.22` for some purpose, already install everything for fvm and only change the path in `settings.json` but the file is not there in `.vscode` i cannot find it anywhere

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the file manually.

`.vscode/settings.json`:

```
{
  "dart.flutterSdkPath": ".fvm/flutter_sdk",
  // Remove .fvm files from search
  "search.exclude": {
    "**/.fvm": true
  },
  // Remove from file watching
  "files.watcherExclude": {
    "**/.fvm": true
  }
}
```

Source: [Configure fvm for VSCode](https://fvm.app/docs/getting_started/configuration)